# FLUTTER Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method map#waitForMap on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_maps_0)

Tags: android, flutter, controller

I have integrated Google Map very well in my Flutter project. For days I have tested it on Android  Emulator, Android devices and iOS Simulator. all seemed well. Then I mostly focused on testing on iOS Simulator. But last night, when I run the project on Android Device and Emulator, the map opened but was not responsive. I had this error :

```
**E/flutter (18971): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method map#waitForMap on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_maps_0)
E/flutter (18971): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:165:7)
E/flutter (18971): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18971): #1      GoogleMapController.init (package:google_maps_flutter/src/controller.dart:30:5)
E/flutter (18971): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18971): #2      _GoogleMapState.onPlatformViewCreated (package:google_maps_flutter/src/google_map.dart:394:44)
E/flutter (18971): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18971):**
```

This error only affects the Android side, not the iOS one ! Upon investigating, I found out that the **Google Map Controller** was failing to initialize ! What can be the cause, and how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Set ***minSdkVersion*** in ***android/app/build.gradle***

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 20
    }
}
```

Specify your API key in the application manifest ***android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml***

```
<manifest ...
  <application ...
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
               android:value="YOUR KEY HERE"/>
```

run `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get` then `flutter run`

Comment: as I said, everything was fine all along. minSdkVersion is already 20, and I have added the API_KEY. it was fine earlier on.

Comment: did you try flutter clean @FrancisNdubaNumbi and using the latest version of the package?

Comment: I did many times already. but the problem persists !